# Get value in app.config

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the `Key` in `app.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SourceWindow" value="C:\Windows" />
</appSettings>
```

And in `MainWindow.xaml` have:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="keyFiles" MethodName="GetFiles" ObjectType="{x:Type io:Directory}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <sys:String> GET VALUE IN APP.CONFIG </sys:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

How i can get value in `app.config` -> `<add key="SourceWindow" value="C:\Windows" />` and set this value in  `<sys:String> VALUE </sys:String>`
by `xaml`?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue, you can write your own [MarkupExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension(v=vs.110).aspx).

I prepared a short sample code for you. First of all let's see the MarkupExtension class that retrive the app.Config's appSettings:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class AppSettingsExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        private string key;

        public AppSettingsExtension()
        {
        }

        public AppSettingsExtension(string key)
        {
            Key = key;
        }

        public string Key
        {
            get
            {
                return key;
            }
            set
            {
                key = value;
            }
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Key];
        }
    }
}
```

Now it is possible to use the `AppSettingsExtension` in a XAML (not inside a `<sys:String />` node, since it already returns a string object):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" Name="win"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:io="clr-namespace:System.IO;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="400">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:AppSettings Key="SourceWindow" x:Key="str" />

        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="keyFiles" MethodName="GetFiles" ObjectType="{x:Type io:Directory}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <local:AppSettings Key="SourceWindow" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{StaticResource str}" Margin="4" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource keyFiles}}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

I hope my sample can help you.

Comment: This is the right way to do this. My answer works but this answer is so much cleaner. Thanks Vic, enjoy this +1 from me.